# DocuSign Workflow Requirement - need 2 approvers not dependent on one another but need both approvals before moving forward

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

In the code below I need to understand how to configure the DocuSign envelope to go to 2 signers in parallel and once they are both done signing send to the next recipient in the workflow.  These 2 approvers are not dependent on one another, but both of their signatures are needed before going to #4 (Signer 2) in the workflow.

Workflow:
Envelope sent to Signer 1 – Customer – for signature. 
Envelope sent to Approver 1 (finance static email address) –Finance – for Approval.
Envelope sent to Approver 2 (static email address) – VP Sales – for Approval.
Envelope sent to Signer 2 (static email address) – VP Sales – for Signature.

```
CURRENT CODE:
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} 

//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES=''; 
//*************************************************// 

//DocuSign Template
var DST=''; 
//Adding Notes & Attachments
var LA='0';
//Custom Recipient List
var CRL='Email~ORDERS@ORDERS.com;FirstName~Finance;LastName~Team;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,Email~{!Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerEmail__c};LastName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerName__c)};Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
//Custom Contact Role Map
var CCRM='Decision Maker~Signer 1;Signer 2~Signer 2;Signer 3~Signer 3';
//Custom Contact Type Map
var CCTM='Signer 1~Signer;Signer 2~Signer;Signer 3~Signer';
//Custom Email Subject
var CES='{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.Account_Name_Docusign__c)} - Please eSign Vocus Sales Agreement';
//Custom Email Message
var CEM='I am sending you this request for your electronic signature, please review and electronically sign by following the link below.';


//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

Comment: I'm not very up to speed with Salesforce apex code, but what does the above code currently do?  Does it send to 1, 2, 3, 4 all separately?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily configurable using the **`CRL`** variable, which stands for Custom Recipient List.  Right now you have

```
var CRL='Email~ORDERS@ORDERS.com;FirstName~Finance;LastName~Team;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,Email~{!Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerEmail__c};LastName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerName__c)};Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~3,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
```

If you just change the routing order of the 3rd recipient from `3` to `2`, so that recipients 2 and 3 BOTH have RoutingOrder~2, then that will send to both of the recipients at routingOrder #2 at the same time.  Basically just change to this:

```
var CRL='Email~ORDERS@ORDERS.com;FirstName~Finance;LastName~Team;Role~Signer 2;RoutingOrder~2,Email~{!Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerEmail__c};LastName~{!JSENCODE(Opportunity.OppOwnerManagerName__c)};Role~Signer 3;RoutingOrder~2,LoadDefaultContacts~1';
```

Notice the changed `RoutingOrder~2` near the end of the line.